# Get the latest record with filter in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to get the latest Django model object but cannot seem to succeed.

Neither of these are working:

```
obj = Model.objects.filter(testfield=12).latest()
```

```python
obj = Model.objects.latest().filter(testfield=12)
```

Comment: Have you tried: `obj= Model.objects.filter(testfield=12).order_by('-id')[:1]`

Comment: @catherine, working like a charm! :D. you want to write this as answer so i can check it?

Comment: In 2018 `NewsPostImage.objects.filter(newsPostTarget=img_id).first()` . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
obj= Model.objects.filter(testfield=12).order_by('-id')[0]
```

Comment: @DaveMerwin it's not incorrect; there are multiple ways of solving this problem, and both this answer and the other are correct.

Comment: Note this makes the assumption that id is a sequenced primary key integer. Which is normally the default for django, but sometimes not.

Comment: This could be dangerous because filter could return an empty list

Comment: '-id' is used to reverse the order!

Comment: maybe .first() instead of [0] ?

Comment: Better to favor Django functions than to manipulate data. This saves computing time. The answer offered by [@Pranav-singh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21978418/11120444) is quite satisfactory

Comment: Don't do that in Teradata database

Answer (score 161):

See the docs from django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest

You need to specify a field in latest(). eg.

```
obj= Model.objects.filter(testfield=12).latest('testfield')
```

Or if your model’s Meta specifies get_latest_by, you can leave off the `field_name` argument to `earliest() or latest()`. Django will use the field specified in `get_latest_by` by default.

Comment: Does "testfield" have to be a date field?

Comment: You must be aware that by adding '.latest('testfield')' the result is no more a queryset.

Answer (score 65):

[last()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#last)   [latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#latest)

Usign last():

```
ModelName.objects.last()
```

using latest():

```
ModelName.objects.latest('id')
```

Answer (score 21):

`latest` is really designed to work with date fields (it probably does work with other total-ordered types too, but not sure). And the only way you can use it without specifying the field name is by setting the `get_latest_by` meta attribute, as mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest).

Comment: It does work with primary keys, you can always do something like this:
```Model.objects.latest('id')```

Answer (score 7):

`obj= Model.objects.filter(testfield=12).order_by('-id')[:1]` is the right solution

Answer (score 4):

```
obj = Model.objects.filter(testfield=12).order_by('id').latest('id')
```

1. Filter based on what field you need - in this case is testfield

Model.objects.filter(testfield=12)

2. In order to get the latest record, first you need to sort the queryset. So that it knows to return the last record based on a criteria.

Now, order the results base on your primary key - most of the times the pk=id

Model.objects.filter(testfield=12).order_by('id')

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

> By default, results returned by a QuerySet are ordered by the ordering tuple given by the ordering option in the model’s Meta. You can override this on a per-QuerySet basis by using the order_by method.

3. After you have the queryset and you have sorted it. Get the latest based on the criteria you need - in this case is the id.

Model.objects.filter(testfield=12).order_by('id').latest('id')

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please edit an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can do comparison with this down here.

[image]

`latest('created')` is same as `order_by('-created').first()`
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: They're the same but `latest()` will throw an exception if there are no results in the QuerySet.