# Return only most recent call per caller

Tags: python, django

Let's say you have a model that represents a call log containing: the person you called (calledid), the date of the call (calldate), and wether or not the person called needs to be recontacted or not.

```
class CallLog(models.Model): 
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    calledid = models.BigIntegerField()
    calldate = models.DateField()
    recontact = models.BooleanField()
```

What I would like to do is collect that set of `calledid`'s that in their last call identified that they don't want to be contacted again (`recontact=False`). `calledid` is not unique and the same person could have had more than one call that resulted in no recontact previously so we have to always identify if they should be recontacted on the basis of their most recent calldate.

How would I go about doing that?

---

Here's what I've tried so far... not sure if this works or not yet

```
calls = CallLog.objects.order_by("-calldate")

seen = set()
seencalledid = set()
keep = []

for o in calls:
    if o.calleid not in seen:
        keep.append(o)
    seen.add(o.calledid)
        if o.recontact:
            seencalledid.add(o.callid)

no_recontact = CallLogs.filter(calledid__in = seencalledid).values_list('calledid',flat=True)
```

Comment: Do a query sorted by calldata and check the recontact value?

Comment: This would work if there was only one call per calledid. But because they're not unique this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produced the desired result, but there has to be a snappier way to capture this information.

```
calls = CallLog.objects.order_by("-calldate")

seen = set()
seencallid = set()
keep = []

for o in calls:
    if o.calledid not in seen:
        keep.append(o)
    seen.add(o.calledid)
        if o.recontact:
            seencallid.add(o.callid)

no_recontact = CallLogs.filter(callid__in = seencallid).values_list('calledid',flat=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Several calls per calledid is the reason why you would sort by date. The last record in that sorted list should be what you want
[django - get the latest record with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675672/django-get-the-latest-record-with-filter)

```
Model.objects.filter(calledid=ID).order_by('-calldate')[0]
```

Comment: What I would like to do is collect that SET of `calledid`'s that in their last call identified that they don't want to be contacted again (recontact=False). This would only return one response which I could just get with `.latest()`.