# Django: Fetch most recently inserted SPECIFIC field value in database error:need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a database consisting multiple fields, but I just want to get the value of one field ("name") which is most recently inserted into the database.

There are some codes that I tried in views.py, but they all return errors:

```
name=Record.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).latest('id')
name=Record.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).latest('name')
name=Record.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).order_by('-id')[:1]
name=Record.objects.values('name').latest('id')
```

erorrs: need more than 1 value to unpack

How can I resolve this issue? thanks.

The views.py code for your reference.

```
class XXXView(ListView):
    context_object_name = XXX'
    template_name = 'XXX.html'

    queryset = xxx.objects.all()
    name=entry.objects.latest('id').name

    if name is not None:
        queryset=queryset.filter(name=name)

    sales=xxx.objects.filter(queryset).aggregate(Sum('sales'))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(XXXView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bbb'] = entry.objects.order_by('-id')[:1]
        return context
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675672/django-get-the-latest-record-with-filter

Comment: @gplayer, I tried this as seen in my question but also return the same error: need more than 1 value to unpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `latest` and `order_by` methods needs to be run on a `Queryset`. The values_list method returns a list so that is why you get an error.

In addition, latest returns an object, not a `Queryset` so switching the order of the two methods will not be enough since `values_list` also has to be run on a `Queryset`

So, either just use the object:

```
name=Record.objects.latest('id').name
```

or more efficiently:

```
name=Record.objects.only('name').latest('id').name
```

Just as a note. Using the latest function in this way might be misleading. Using the latest with `id` as a parameter will give you the object with the largest `id` in the database. Depending on what you want it might be better to add a `DateTimeField` with an auto_now_add/auto_now instead and use that as the basis for the latest query. This will make it more clear what "latest" means in your specific case.

If find the QuerySet documentation to be really good: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/

And if you want to test things out to find the problem yourself next time I can really recommend running `python manage.py shell` and importing your model to test your one liners. You should most likely look into tests as well which can give you a better interface for troubleshooting once things get more complicated: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/

Comment: thanks a lot. But I tried all the answers listed in this post, but still return the same error. So I was wondering if there is anything related to my code. Please see uploaded views.py snippet, hope you could help find the cause of my mistake. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace as well?

Comment: ,hi, I have changed to another method to show the data in views.py, so this issue has been solved. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask for the name after the `latest()`, i.e.:

```
name=Record.objects.latest('id').name
```

`values('name')` throws away everything except the names, so after that call you can't find the last id any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
name = Record.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).last()
```

`latest(field_name)` returns the latest object in the table, by date, using the field_name provided as the date field.