# django get to every user if its latest record match given value in table

Tags: python, django, django-models, filter, django-database

I want to filter students if his last record transaction_type match with given value.

For example Student Ali has 3 record in transaction table. And if the latest records transaction_type == 'busy' I want to get this transaction otherwise I want to pass this transaction

My Models like that

```
class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.durum

class Student(models.Model):
    ogr_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    ad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    soyad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bolum = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    dogum_yeri = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sehir = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ilce = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True, null=True)
    nufus_sehir = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True, null=True)
    nufus_ilce = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.ogr_no + " " + self.ad + " " + self.soyad 

class Transaction(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='islemogrenci')
    transaction_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    yardim = models.ForeignKey(Yardim, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    aciklama = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True, null=True)
    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    transaction_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.ad + " " + self.transaction_type.durum
```

> Note: I use Postgres as Database Engine

Comment: Does this solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675672/get-the-latest-record-with-filter-in-django

Comment: Unfortunately, in my example students have multiple records in transaction table but i want to only check their latest record

Comment: Alright, got your point, added answer, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to get the latest records of all students and then check the `transaction_type`.

```
latest_records = Transaction.objects.values('student').annotate(
    latest_record=Max('id')
)

transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(
    id__in=latest_records.values('latest_record'),
    transaction_type='busy'
)
```

Comment: It doesnt work still showing Students who is his last record 'available'. His first record is busy but I want to this Student if his last record is busy. I think its my bad I will try something.

Comment: Can you show transaction records with `id`, `student` and  `transaction_type` column for Transaction? `Transaction.objects.values('id', 'student', 'transaction_type')`?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I guess the reason it didn't work at first time was because I was passing the data through excel in random order. Could we do this in the same way, but checking which is the closest to the time in the Transaction record instead of record save order?

Comment: You can do so my adding `created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` in `Transaction`, and then using `latest_records = Transaction.objects.values('student').annotate(latest_record=Max('created_at'))`